# Linker can't find function

Tags: android, c++, gcc

Im trying to build an Ubuntu Touch tree, based on an Aosp tree I already correctly built.
It fails with this error

> CAPEWrapper.cpp:16: error: undefined reference to '__xlog_buf_printf'

this is the header that file includes

```
#include "CAPEWrapper.h"
```

which on cascade includes

```
#include <cutils/xlog.h>
```

which in turn defines

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

int __xlog_buf_printf(int bufid, const struct xlog_record *rec, ...);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

I suspect that my g++ doesn't set __cplusplus macro. Could it be a realistic scenario with this kind of error? If this could be the problem, should I need to specify a standard implementation with "stdc=something" to solve it?

Any other idea is welcome.

Comment: That code from xlog.h is only a function *declaration*, not a function *definition*. The function must be defined elsewhere, either in a .c/.cpp file that needs to be compiled into the project, or in a library to be linked. Is there a cutils/xlog.c* file?

Comment: There's no xlog.c* into the whole tree. Since the project is huge, could you tell me a pattern to grep to find where the function is defined?

OT
Just for my knowledge: what have been the error if the problem was that the compiler shouldn't find the function declaration?

Comment: If there's no xlog.c*, then the function is probably defined in a library that needs to be linked, rather than a source file that needs to be compiled. In that case, the header file exists to merely tell the compiler that a function of that name exists and has the argument types and return type specified, and the compiler then depends on the linker to link a library containing the actual code for the function. So, I recommend you try the solution posted by Jeremy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found that the modules was listed inside a macro called LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES, that in Android environment passes its content to the --whole-archive flag of GCC linker.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your project is linking `libcutils`, and that it's linking it in the correct order (i.e. that `-lcutils` appears in the linker command line *after* any module that depends on it).

Comment: This is an extract of the Android.mk that builds the project
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=       \
            libbinder               \
            libutils                \
            libcutils               \
            libdl                   \
            libui

As you can see, libcutils is into the macro.

Comment: Linking order, thank you! My project generator of choice doesn't order links based on dependency, and they were ordered alphabetically instead of by dependency. Thanks for reminding me.